# Problems with adding UIPickerView and UIToolBar to UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I am quite new to coding iOS, hope you can help me with this, thank you.

I've added an `UIToolBar` with some `UIBarButtonItem` and an `UIPickerView` to the xib, and want to add them into an `UIActionSheet` in code. The `UIToolBar`, `UIBarButtonItem`, `UIPickerView` and `UIActionSheet` are properties and I do it like:

```
_pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216);
[_actionSheet addSubview:_toolBar];
[_actionSheet addSubview:_pickerView];
```

As you can see in the image below, there are some problems with it:

1. the `UIBarButtonItem`s are missing
2. the `UIToolBar` should be in black
3. the `UIPickerView` seems too big that the right side is missing

I know I can do all of this programmatically, but I think it's better to put UI stuff in xib. Can anyone tell me how to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pls explain a bit more what do you wonna achieve with this configuration. UIActionSheet is in general used with buttons. It slides in from the button an presents you with options on how to proceed with a given task.

Comment: I think you are using actionsheet just for animation. You should write simple animation code rather than adding picker and toolbar to actionsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I added an `UIView` to wrap the toolbar and the picker, and then added it to the `UIActionSheet` in code:

```
[_actionSheet addSubview:_wrapper];
```

the layout is fine after doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you check out UIActionSheetPicker by Tim Cinel.  It has really made stuff like this simpler for me, and the examples are really easy to follow and understand.

Here's the link: https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

(Old Link <s>https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker</s>)

This has a bar above the UIPickerView for buttons like Done/Cancel, but I have found that modifying the code to change these buttons is relatively easy as well.

Comment: @flipper New version is https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0 please, update your link

Answer (score 1):

For getting the desired result which is shown in Above photo......i recomand you the Programing approach is better then the xib approch

i think you a re trying to implement a picker action sheet with Done button. i will refer using segemnt control instead of using toolbar.

Use this following code where you want to show action sheet with picker and Done button.

```
UIActionSheet *Example_Actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil  delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil  
                                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];  

    Ex_Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
    Ex_Picker.delegate = self;  
    Ex_Picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    // note this is default to NO  
    Example_Actionsheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [Example_Actionsheet addSubview:Bedroom_Picker];  
    [Example_Actionsheet showInView:self.view]; 
    [Example_Actionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Close_method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [Example_Actionsheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [Example_Actionsheet release];
```

and if you want to use Toolbar

```
pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
```

And add the toolbar and picker in subview of actionsheet.

```
[aac addSubview:"Your toolbar"];
[aac addSubview:"Your picker"];
```

and set the action sheet frame. its done with toolbar.

Comment: thank you! i've seen segment control and toolbar for implementing pickerview with done button. can you tell me the advantage of using segment control instead of toolbar?

Comment: if i still can't solve this problem, maybe i'll just switch back to programming approach...

Comment: There is no specific advantage......for using segement control over toolbar. but by using segment control code become simple and contact. it is also possible to implement with toolbar. i will post the code for toolbar too by which you can implement this thing by toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code use for the Add Toolbar As a Subview.

```
-(IBAction)btnOption:(id)sender{

            self.tBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
            self.pkrMain.frame=CGRectMake(0, 47, 320, 216);

           self.act=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:lblReam delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:lblOk destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OptionA",@"OptionB",nil];

            [self.act addSubview:self.tBar];
            [self.act addSubview:self.pkrMain];

            [self.pkrMain reloadAllComponents];
            [self.act clipsToBounds];
            [self.act showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        }
```